# retrieve date from POST into datediff problem

Tags: php, date, date-difference

so i want to get the value of $dob and put it in date diff to get only the years difference. the code below works fine. but my problem is when i try to get the $dob from $POST i get the following error: Uncaught Exception DateTime:__construct(); failed to parse time string (27-12-2010) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character.

can someone give me a clue how to fix this, thanks in advance.

```
    $dob = "27-12-2010";
    $age = $dob;  
    $date = new DateTime($age);
    $now = new DateTime();
    $ageResult = $date->diff($now)->format("%y");
```

what i'm trying to do:

```
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $dob = $age;
    $date = new DateTime($dob);
    $now = new DateTime();
    $ageResult = $date->diff($now)->format("%y");

and then put the $ageResult in the DB query
```

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime constructor needs to know what format the string is in when you pass it. Use the [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) static method.

```
$dob = "27-12-2010";
$age = $dob;  
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $age);
$now = new DateTime();
$ageResult = $date->diff($now)->format("%y");
```